# PHP 8.1 throws error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php

I am checking all my code in readiness for upgrading to PHP 8.1.

The following lines of code work fine in PHP7.4 but throws the above error on the line starting with "$pcount" in PHP 8.1

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
            $pcount[$product['HospitalProductID']] += 1;
        }
```

The $product array looks like this:

```
(
    [HospitalProductID] => 260
    [HospitalProtocolID] => 82
)
```

Any idea why PHP 8.1 does not like this code?

UPDATE
I believe I found the cause of this issue and posting it here un case it might help others in the future.

The error is caused by the use of the += operator in conjunction with an array key that does not yet exist, therefore trying to add 1 to an undefined value.

I changed my code as follows and I no longer get the error.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        if (isset($pcount[$product['HospitalProductID']])) {
            $pcount[$product['HospitalProductID']] += 1;
        } else {
            $pcount[$product['HospitalProductID']] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `$products` is an array then `$product` will be the integer value. `$product['HospitalProductID']` does not exist.

Comment: $products is an indexed array.  $product is the contents of one key of $products and it contains the HospitalProductID ket with a value of 260 so yes, $product[HospitalProductID] does exist.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.4 was just being kind to you in the past. Part of PHP8 is to do away with a lot auto fixing and other nonsense that indulged bad coding and vulnerabilities.

Re write what you have to :

```
$products = ["HospitalProductID" => 260, "HospitalProtocolID" => 82];

foreach ($products as $product => $id) {

}
```

`$product` is your Item and `$id` is your int.

**UPDATE:**

Since you have confirmed you are using MYSQLI, you should be using MYSQLI fetch functions like :

`fetch_object(`) Returns your results as an Object.

```
if ( $products = $mysqli->query( $sql ) ) {
    while ( $product = $products->fetch_object() ) {
        $product->HospitalProductID;

    }
}
$products->close();
```

`fetch_assoc()` Returns your results as an Associative Array.

```
if ( $products = $mysqli->query( $sql ) ) {
    while ( $product = $products->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $product['HospitalProductID'];

    }
}
$products->close();
```

Here is a list of all possible methods you can use with the result class: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

I would also implore you to check out Prepared Statements. Especially if you are allowing any type of input from out with the hardcoding of the script: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite following this.  

The $products array is returned from a SELECT query on my database so it's an indexed array with each key containing a HospitalProductID key and a HospitalProtocolID key.

Are you saying that there should be a inner foreach loop like the one you included that looks for the key I need within the value returned by the outer foreach loop?

Comment: I guess the real problem is that I don;t understand what the error message is complaining about so don't know how to fix it. $pcount[$product['HospitalProductID']] += 1 should resolve to $pcount[260] += 1 which seems valid to me.

Comment: @Pete Ah, So its a database run. What are you using? Mysqli, PDO? Could you provide an example of your columns aswell

Comment: mysqli.  The column names are the ones you see in my original post and they are both type int in the database.  Here's a complete dump of what comes back from the mysqli query and would be in $products:
```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HospitalProductID] => 233
            [HospitalProtocolID] => 825
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HospitalProductID] => 258
            [HospitalProtocolID] => 824
        )

)```

Comment: @Pete You should be using mysqli then. I'll update

Comment: I'm not sure what your update has to do with the error I'm getting.  I"m using myslqi, prpeared statements, and fetc_assoc to return the results of all my queries and have done so for years.  The array I posted in my previous comment is what is returned from fetch_assoc.

Comment: @pete, based on the code you added you are returning the column name not the value. Your foreach loop should be $products as $product => $value, But even then its not really intoe with how you should be fetching these results.